# C++: Fastest method to check if all array elements are equal

Tags: c++, arrays

What is the fastest method to check if all elements of an array(preferable integer array) are equal. Till now I have been using the following code:

```
bool check(int array[], int n)
{   
    bool flag = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)      
    {         
        if(array[i] != array[i + 1])
            flag = 1;
    }

    return flag;
}
```

Comment: You don't need `flag` simply return `false` in the cycle and true below it. Otherwise I think this is as efficient as you can get.

Comment: Why on earth asign `1` and `0` to a `bool`?

Comment: @ChristianRau: people are funny like that, they see a weakly typed language like C++ and go nuts. Some people would even assign `0` and `1` to a `long`, relying on the implicit conversion!

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl You mean `memcmp` for comparing two `int`s? I don't think so. Just to be sure, you not one of those thinking he wants to compare two ranges, aren't you?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
int check(const int a[], int n)
{   
    while(--n>0 && a[n]==a[0]);
    return n!=0;
}
```

Comment: So in reaction to his incorrect use of `bool` types you just turned the return type into an `int` to be on the safe side? ;)

Comment: Well, in this case it would be off-topic for the actual question, wouldn't it? Well, up-voted it anyway ;)

Comment: If you find using a decreasing index appealing, I would suggest not using `a[0]` as the constant. You start comparing `a[0]` and `a[length-1]` which are at opposite ends of the array, incurring two RAM round trips (for arrays longer than 64 bytes) before the comparison can start.

Comment: Great code. I would change n!=0 to n>0, to handle case where n=0

Comment: Can we get some perf comparisons vs Paul R's answer?

Answer (score 18):

Here is a solid solution which is valid C++11.
The advantages is that you do not need to manually play with the indexes or iterators. It is a best practice to

> prefer algorithm calls to handwritten loops [Herb Sutter - C++ Coding Standards]

I think this will equally efficient as Paul R's solution.

```
bool check(const int a[], int n)
{
      return !std::all_of(a, a+n, [a](int x){ return x==a[0]; });
}
```

Comment: With my crude unit measurement skills on a Core i5, this implementation appears to check at a rate of ~0.7 ns per element, which is pretty fast but believable. Did you try hoisting a[0] out of the loop as Paul R did? When I did, it dropped down to 6.4e-10 ns per element, which I find unbelievable. I assume I have made a mistake, and that my crude measurements are no longer capturing the computation in the second case. Does anyone else have measurements?

Comment: Did Herb Sutter really say 'algorithm calls'? Or something like 'standard library calls'? Citation?

Comment: @EJP 
Herb Sutter, Andrei Alexandrescu - C++ Coding Standards: 101 Rules, Guidelines, and Best Practices,
Publisher: Addison-Wesley Professional; 1 edition (November 4, 2004),
ISBN-10: 9780321113580,
pages 162 - 164

Comment: Well, this works when the array is empty as well (i.e., when `n` is zero).

Answer (score 14):

Once you have found a mismatching element you can break out of the loop:

```
bool check(const int array[], int n)
{   
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)      
    {         
        if (array[i] != array[i + 1])
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

If this is performance-critical then it can be further optimised slightly as:

```
bool check(const int array[], int n)
{   
    const int a0 = array[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)      
    {         
        if (array[i] != a0)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Yes that would definitely make it faster. Thanks, and I'll keep in mind the code formatting when I post next.

Comment: Using a constant element (the first, typically) to compare all other elements against allow the compiler to hoist the load of it outside the loop. Not sure there would be much of an impact though.

Answer (score 5):

Recast the array to a larger data type. Eg, operate on 64bit ints, or use SSE or AVX intrinsics for 128 or 256 bit operation. For example, the SSE2 intrinsic is _mm_cmpeq_epi32, whose result you'll use with _mm_or_si128. Check the result with repeated application of _mm_srli_si128 and _mm_cvtsi128_si32. Check the result every few hundred iterations for early exit.

Make sure to operate on aligned memory, check the unaligned start and end as ints, and check the first packed element with itself.

Comment: Maybe we can reuse glibc's `memcmp` (already assembly optimized) as such: 1) Split the array into to parts of equal size. 2) Compare them 3) If different, return false. Else take the first half, ignore the second) 4) Split the first half into two. 5) ... This leads to only N comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

For programmer efficiency you may try the following all in one line.

```
vector<int> v{1, 1, 1, 1};
all_of(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), [&r=v[0]](int value){ return value == r; }->bool);
```

I did not test run this code, let me know if there is syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

We'll it's basically an O(n) operation so you can't do much better than what you have, other than dispensing with the flag and just `return false;` on the first failure and `return true;` after the iteration.

Comment: Just because it is O(n) does not mean it can't be optimized. What a pointless thing to say.

Comment: Please explain the "...pointless thing..." I said. The upper bound on the runtime is and will always be O(n) and my suggestion to failfast on the first mismatch is (lacking more details) a rather good optimization!

Comment: Specifically, "it is O(n) so you can't do better" is senseless. It demonstrates over-schooling that has rotted the mind. Eg, accessing data on my hd is O(n). Does that mean I can't do much better with an ssd? This alg can be sped up by operating on larger words (using sse), for sake of argument. Does that not count as much better? Order is order, but the coefficient matters a great deal too.

Comment: Please quote me correctly. I wrote "...can't do **much** better...". Perhaps I should have clarified that even more, writing "...can't do orders of magnitude better...", but I assumed that educated persons such as yourself would be able to infer that. I agree that you can optimize the original code and introduce all kinds of processor specific tricks, but the fact remains that it *still* is a linear operation.

Comment: You are still incorrect, an O(n) operation can be optimized by orders of magnitude. Whether by moving from a cpu to gpu, hd to ssd, interpreted lang to compiled, a special cpu instruction, a sane reimplementation of an algorithm, or even by a clever optimization fit for a particular problem (eg imagine in this case the array elements are typically very different but sometimes all identical. Then, early exit will give orders of magnitude speedup.)

Answer (score 0):

```
bool check(int array[],int n)
{       
  // here 1st element is checked with others. This decreases the number of iteration by 1.
  // also it returns immediately. 
  // The requirement is to check if all the elements are equal. 
  // So if 1st element is equal to others then all elements are equal. 
  // Otherwise the  elements are not equal.
  for(int i=1;i<n;i++)      
  {         
    if(array[0]!=array[i])
      return false;
  }        
  return true;
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. It just compares the first and second elements of the array and exits immediately.

Comment: if you do it this way it should be `for(int i=1;i<n;i++)` and the `else` breaks it, the `return 1` should happen outside the loop and the 1/0 are flipped, should return 1 when not equal and 0 if all are equal

Comment: @Paul:The condition is changed.

Comment: It's still broken - hint: one of the return statements is in the wrong place.

Comment: should return true/false instead of 0/1, note the return type is bool

Comment: @billz: will it not auto convert?

Comment: it should be but not best code, should try to build warning free program. your compiler should give one warning for your return type. :)

Comment: @Rain It will automatically convert, but that doesn't magically make it correct and type-aware programming style. In the end you could also just return `42` for `true` and `std::string("Hello World").empty()` for `false`, but well.

Comment: Mmmmm, I think I would have deleted my answer several comments in ..:)

Comment: Hmmmmm. Instead of deleting the answer its better to know where the fault is!!

Comment: In the end it doesn't even decrease the number of iterations at all. Superficially seen, comparing with the first element might reduce memory access, but in the end `array[i-1]` should be in cache anyway (if the compiler hasn't already done some otpimization).

Answer (score 0):

Find a library that's available on your platform that supports threading or parallel-for loops, and split the computation out such that different cores test different ranges of the array.

Some available libraries are listed here:

http://parallel-for.sourceforge.net/parallelfor.html

Or possibly, you can make use of the parallism that many GPU's offer.

Comment: This is not a problem that lends itself to parallelism since the big problem here will be memory bandwidth, so instead of one thread waiting on the RAM access, you've now got multiple threads waiting even longer on RAM access. The IA32 architecture means a single thread would be best due to the hardware memory streaming.

Comment: yup. also if the arrays are small, they will stay in one processor's cache

Comment: I agree the benefits are dependant on system architecture and the nature of the data being analysed. If the goal is to find the fastest method though, I am sure there are scenarios where parallizing will be faster than running through the data serially.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, I would propose this:

```
bool check_single(const int a[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
        if (a[0] != a[n]) { return false; }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Compared to other (already proposed) versions:

- `a[0]` will be hoisted outside the loop by the compiler, meaning a single array access within the loop
- we loop from 0 to n, which is better (access-wise) than loading `a[0]` and then looping from `a[n]`

Obviously, it still checks N elements and thus is O(N).

Comment: this would return `true` if _any_ two elements are equal.  Possibly you wanted the equality check to be an inequality check?

Comment: ... you prefer single-state booleans?

Comment: @xtofl: Yep! Exactly! :D

Answer (score 0):

fast hash mapping technique:

```
bool areSame(int a[],int n)
{
    unordered_map<int,int> m; //hash map to store the frequency od every

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
       m[a[i]]++;
      
    if(m.size()==1)
       return true;
    else
       return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the following is more readable than the highest rated answer and I would wager more efficient too (but havent benchmarked)

```
bool check(int a[], int n)
{   
    if (n)
    {
        auto first = a[0];
        
        for(int i = 1; i < n; i++)      
        {         
            if(array[i] != first) return false;
        }
        
        return true;
    }

    return true;    //change to false for the OPs logic.  I prefer logical true here
}
```

Comment: _...I would wager more efficient too..._ Absolutely the opposite is correct.

Answer (score -2):

```
bool check_identity (int a[], int b[], const int size)
{
    int i;
    i = 0;
    while ((i < size-1) && (a[i] == b[i]))   i++;

    return (a[i] == b[i]);

}
```

Comment: The question had only 1 array.