# Test if all elements of a vector are equal

Tags: c++

I want to test if a non-empty vector contains identical elements. Is this the best way?

```
count(vecSamples.begin()+1, vecSamples.end(), vecSamples.front()) == vecSamples.size()-1;
```

Comment: It is simple, sure, but inefficient if they are different.  Plus you could simplify it further by removing the +/- 1's.  Especially since this would blow up on an empty vector.

Comment: `vecSamples.front()` would blow up on an empty vector.

Comment: The vector is never empty in my case.

Comment: Is your vector always at least 2 elements though?

Comment: No, is that a problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++: Fastest method to check if all array elements are equal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14120346/c-fastest-method-to-check-if-all-array-elements-are-equal)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking if all elements of a vector are equal in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20287095/checking-if-all-elements-of-a-vector-are-equal-in-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @john correctly points out, your solution iterates over the entire container even if the first two elements are different, which is quite a waste.

How about a purely no-boost no c++11 required solution?

```
bool allAreEqual = 
  find_if(vecSamples.begin() + 1, 
    vecSamples.end(), 
    bind1st(not_equal_to<int>(), vecSamples.front())) == vecSamples.end();
```

Stops on first non-equal element found.
Just make sure your vecSamples is non-empty before running this.

Answer (score 9):

In c++11 (or [Boost Algorithm](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/algorithm/doc/html/algorithm/CXX11.html))

```
std::all_of(vecSamples.begin()+1,vecSamples.end(),
          [&](const T & r) {return r==vecSamples.front();})
```

Comment: I'm aware of the fact that OP is asking about a *non-empty* vector. Even so, I think that adding `!vecSamples.empty() ||` to your expression before the call to `std::all_of()` wouldn't damage your answer. What do you think?

Comment: Simply replacing the `vecSamples.begin()+1` with just `vecSamples.begin()` in your call to `std::all_of()` also makes your code suitable for working with empty vectors, since the predicate won't be evaluated on an empty vector.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not, because it always examines all the elements of the vector even if the first two elements are different. Personally I'd just write a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

If your vector contains at least one element:

```
std::equal(vecSamples.begin() + 1, vecSamples.end(), vecSamples.begin())
```