# Fastest way to find out if all elements in a vector are false or true c++?

Tags: c++, vector

I was wondering if there was a quick way to find out if all elements in a vector are **false** or **true**? Like instead of *checking each element using a loop?*

Comment: Not really, other than picking another container, e.g. `bitset`, but look into `any_of` and `all_of`.

Comment: No. That would penalize far more useful operations. The standard algorithms might be specialized for your case though. Or not.

Comment: If you can treat `true\false` as `1\0`, try turning it into a `k-th order statistic` problem. Find just the first and last values in `O(log.n)` time. If they're same, you know they are all one value.

Comment: Brushed up on my memory and you actually need an order statistic tree structure to get these in `O(log.n)`. Without specialized structures it would be `O(n)`. Worth a thought if you're really after the fastest possible way but perhaps overkill otherwise.

Answer (score 38):

I'd take advantage of the new algorithms for clarity:

```
// all true
std::all_of(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](bool v) { return v; });

// all false
std::all_of(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](bool v) { return !v; });
std::none_of(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](bool v) { return v; });
```

You can't find out if all the elements in a vector are true without actually checking every element of the vector. Best-case, you reinterpret the memory differently and check more than 1 element at a time, but you still have to check everything until you find one that fails your test.

Comment: so if all of my values in vec are true it returns true?

Comment: @LoveMeow Which syntax? This only works with C++11 lambdas and algorithms. For non-C++11, I would check out either [Cyber's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26896072/2069064) answer or [MSalters'](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26898832/2069064)

Comment: Instead of `[](bool v) { return v; }`, you can also `#include <functional>` and do `std::all_of(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::identity);`

Comment: `std::identity` is available only in c++20.

Answer (score 9):

Easiest IMO is the free `find` function

```
if (std::find(begin(v), end(v), true) == end(v)) // All false
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `std::accumulate()`:

```
int sum = std::accumulate(std::begin(v), std::end(v), 0);

if (sum == v.size()) {
    // All true
}
else if (sum) {
    // Any true, any false
}
else {
    // All false
}
```

Comment: This won't tell you if all elements are true.

Comment: @Ferruccio Right. You can compare it with its size: `if (accu..() == v.size())`

Answer (score 1):

This requires looping, but will at least take advantage of short-ciruiting behavior.

```
bool all = true;
std::vector<bool>::iterator it = myVec.begin();

while(all && it != myVec.end())  // Stops early if it hits a false
{
    all &= *it;
    ++it;
}
```

If `all` is `true`, all elements in the vector were true. If `all` is false, at least one element was not `true`.

Comment: Correction: "if `all` is false, at least one element was not `true`".
(or at least one element was `false`)

Comment: @abelenky Good catch :) "Do as I do, not as I say"... or something like that.

Comment: This won't tell you if all elements are false.

Comment: @Ferruccio Correct, this would be the analog to Python's `all` function. The complement `any` would tell you if all elements are `false`, which would be similar to this code but with a few slight modifications.

Answer (score 1):

I also agree that worst case one will have to check every individual element but for all other cases I suggest rephrasing the question:

Are all elements in my collection equal? If so, to what value.

This will return early in both cases and you are done.
Else one additionally will have to check the value of the element (true or false).

For this I would suggest to look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20287095/checking-if-all-elements-of-a-vector-are-equal-in-c).

I want to generalize my answer a bit more: This can be done with any N mutually exclusive predicates A1, ... , AN that I want to check for my collection. For this I will need a function that, given an element of my collection, returns some identifier of the predicate Ai that holds for the element (and a way to check the predicates for equality).

Then again I can apply the above scheme.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most efficient would be:

```
if(v.find(v.begin(), v.end(), true) == v.end())
// All false  

if(v.find(v.begin(), v.end(), false) == v.end())
// All true
```

Answer (score 0):

A more efficient option for large vectors is to replace your `vector<bool>` with a `vector<bitset>`. Then you can simply combine the `any_of()` algorithm with a lambda function invoking the `bitset` member function `any()` (or similarly for `all_of()` and `all()`).

```
    int n = 2000000000, i = 623;
    vector<bitset<256>> bits((n + 255) / 256);
    bits[i >> 8][i & 0xFF] = true;
    cout << bits[i >> 8][i & 0xFF] << endl;
    if (any_of(bits.begin(), bits.end(),
            [](const bitset<256>& bs) { return bs.any(); })) {
        cout << "at least one bit set" << endl;
    }
    for (auto& bs : bits) {
        bs.set();
    }
    if (all_of(bits.begin(), bits.end(),
            [](const bitset<256>&bs) { return bs.all(); })) {
        cout << "all bits set" << endl;
    }
```

In my timing tests with 2 billion elements (release build VS2022), either `any_of()` or `all_of()` above took 20ms (faster if `any_of()` breaks out early). Whereas with `vector<bool>` they required 2200ms. About 100x speedup. Setting all bits took 36ms, as compared to 1930ms for a `vector<bool>`, about 50x speedup.

The interface is slightly messy so you can wrap it in a template class if you want to to clean it up:

```
template <size_t bits_per_bitset, int lg_bits_per_bitset>
class dynamic_bitset {
public:
    dynamic_bitset(int n)
        : v((n + bits_per_bitset - 1)/ bits_per_bitset) { }
    
    constexpr bool operator[](int i) const {
        return v[i >> lg_bits_per_bitset][i & ((1 << lg_bits_per_bitset) - 1)];
    }
    auto operator[](int i) {
        return v[i >> lg_bits_per_bitset][i & ((1 << lg_bits_per_bitset) - 1)];
    }
    bool any() {
        return any_of(v.begin(), v.end(),
            [](const std::bitset<bits_per_bitset>& bs) { return bs.any(); });
    }
    bool all() {
        return all_of(v.begin(), v.end(),
            [](const std::bitset<bits_per_bitset>& bs) { return bs.all(); });
    }
    void set()   { for (auto& bs : v) bs.set(); }
    void reset() { for (auto& bs : v) bs.reset(); }
    void flip()  { for (auto& bs : v) bs.flip(); }
private:
    std::vector<std::bitset<bits_per_bitset>> v;
};
```

Now using it is as simple as this:

```
    int n = 2000000000, i = 623;
    dynamic_bitset<256, 8> bits(n);
    bits[i] = true;
    cout << bits[i] << endl;
    if (bits.any()) {
        cout << "at least one bit set" << endl;
    }
    bits.set();
    if (bits.all()) {
        cout << "all bits set" << endl;
    }
```

If I increase the template parameters, it gets a bit faster, but increases the wasted space if `n` is not divisible by `bits_per_bitset`. In my experiments there were no further returns beyond `<1024,10>`, which occupies a minimum of 32 words of 32 bits each.

You can add a bunch of other operations to `dynamic_bitset` easily including `push_back()`, bitwise operators, `begin()`/`end()`, etc.