# Checking for duplicate values associated with key in map?

Tags: c++

I'm struggling with outputting unique values of a `map<string, vector<string>>` I have. Right now, I have a map, and iterate through it, with the goal of outputting only unique values associated with the specified key.

I do need to keep the duplicate values, or else I'd just remove the dups :)

After looking at **[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32391079/c-how-to-check-if-elements-in-an-array-are-equal/32391112)**, my set up is like the following:

```
 for( const auto& pair : myMap ){

        for( std::size_t i = 0; i < pair.second.size(); ++i ) {

            bool notMatch = (pair.second[i] != pair.second[i+1]){

            if (pair.first == key && notMatch){
                cout << key << " : ";
                cout << pair.second[i] << " - at index -  " << i << "\n";
            }
       }
    }
```

I then get an output along the lines of :

"key : value - at index -  6"

"key : value - at index -  10"

My initial thought was that one of the elements might have some extra characters or something, which would make sense as to why the duplicate elements are not being seen as equal.

But when doing a simple check of -

```
if (pair.second[6] == pair.second[10]){
   cout << "They are equal";
} else {
   cout << "They are NOT equal";
}
```

It confirms and returns that the two elements are in fact equal. Since the elements are equal, I'm struggling to understand why `bool notMatch = (pair.second[i] != pair.second[i+1])` does not consider them to be equal.

Apologies if this was posted incorrectly, I'll edit if necessary.

Thanks for your help

Comment: These links may help you: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique , https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of

Comment: Seems like you are only checking if consecutive elements are equal. This might work if the map was sorted in terms of value, but they are in fact sorted by key. So identical values are not necessarily adjacent while iterating over the map. Edit *"I'm struggling to understand why `bool notMatch = (pair.second[i] != pair.second[i+1])` does not consider them to be equal."* Because `6` and `10` aren't sequential. If `i` is `6` you only compare `pair.second[6]` with `pair.second[7]`. There's no possible value of `i` that would compare the element at position `6` with the one at position `10`.

Comment: Note that `pair.second[i+1]` will be undefined behavior on the last iteration where `i == pair.second.size() - 1`.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Thank you! I'll take a look into those

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Okay okay, that makes sense, thank you

Comment: Quick and dirty: dump all the values from pair.second into a std::set, and output the contents of that. something like `std::set<std:string> mySet; mySet.insert(pair.second.begin(), pair.second.end());`

Comment: @Tzalumen You're my hero

Comment: I'd make it an answer, but it doesn't really address your question, just sidesteps around it using another stl container. One thing to keep in mind: std::set is a sorted container, so you will lose the order in which you inserted elements.

Comment: @Tzalumen Still very helpful nonetheless, learning new things is always great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Tzalumen's comment, you could insert the values in a set or unordered set and compare the size to the original vector:

```
for(const auto& pair : myMap){
    unordered_set<string> s(pair.second.begin(), pair.second.end());
    if (s.size() == pair.second.size()) {
        cout << "value has unique elements" << endl;
    } else { 
        cout << "value has duplicate elements" << endl;
    }
}
```

If the set's size is smaller than the vector's size, you know the vector has duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want duplicates anywhere, why not have a `std::map<std::string, std::set<std::string>>` in the first place?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip, as I stated in my post, I do actually need the duplicates in the original map, otherwise `map<string, set<string>>` would be prefect