# How to check if numbers in array equal?

Tags: c, arrays

How do you check if  numbers in an array are equal?
I have an array with 10 numbers, and I want to check if two or more of the numbers are equal. 
What is the best way to check this?
Thanks.

Comment: What range are the numbers within?  And are they floating point numbers, integers?

Comment: I think the most straightforward way you would be to sort the array and then to compare adjacent elements.

Comment: Sort then adjacent comparisons is the generalized solution, and consumes O(n log n). In specific cases where the range of possible values is limited, use each value as a seconary array's index, and increment that element by one each time that value comes up. As soon as an element has been incremented more than once, you have a dupe. That's a less general solution, but O(n).

Comment: And the optimal generalized algorithm would be to use a C library that provides hashing, and watch for hash collisions. That would be O(n) also, and doesn't place constraints on the input.

Comment: @DavidO I like the hash solution, it would also make it easy to randomize for improved performance if you just need a "yes" or "no" answer to this

Comment: @Brandin If the numbers must be in the range, say, 1 .. 1000, then `int temp[1001]; for( size_t ix = 0; ix < 10; ix++ ) { if( temp[array[ix]]++) { printf "dupe found\n"; break; } }` is faster, but places constraints on the data set.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++: Fastest method to check if all array elements are equal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14120346/c-fastest-method-to-check-if-all-array-elements-are-equal)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this question using the following program of linear search. The following program will not only report the array elements which are equal but also the number of array elements which are equal. Incase any mistakes please let me know :)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a[10], i, j, flag = 0;

    printf("Please Enter 10 Numbers");

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for(j = i + 1; j < 10; j++)
        {
            if(a[i] == a[j])
            {
                flag++;
                printf("Array Element %d and %d are equal", i, j);
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\nThe Equal Numbers In The Array Are = %d", flag);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: False positives when i==j.

Comment: Looks better, but does an unnecessary number of loops - see @simonic answer.

Comment: @MartinJames - I see only answer of mine and one of haccks. :|

Comment: Oh - he's deleted it:)

Comment: @PranavJituri `flag` is never initialised.  Your inner loop is correct but could more efficiently start from `i+1`

Comment: @simonc- Code edited to initialize `flag` and started the inner loop from `i+1`. :)

Comment: @PranavJituri What is the purpose of `i!=j` if `j` is starting from `i+1`

Comment: @rullof - oops. That was before the previous editing. Anyways code has been re-edited again. Thanks for pointing out that :)

Answer (score 1):

For an unsorted array, it is better to sort the array first. I used the `qsort` function to sort the array. After sorting the array, I compare the adjacent element for each of the element.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 10


int cmpfunc (const void * a, const void * b)
{
   return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}

int main()
{
   int values[] = { 88, 56, 100, 2, 100, 56, 56, 56, 2, 1 };
   int count = 0;
   qsort(values, 5, sizeof(int), cmpfunc);

   for( int i = 0 ; i < SIZE-1; i++ )
   {
      if(values[i] == values[i+1])
        count++;
   }
   printf("%d dupes", count);

   return(0);
}
```

Comment: Won't it be O(n^2)?  (As you'll need to loop through gradually shorter lists up to n-2 times to be sure of spotting any duplicate. (not the downvoter btw)

Comment: @simonc; AFAIK; Linear search algo is of order n.

Comment: @haccks Then please provide an example of how you would detect dupes in an unsorted list using a single pass linear search without knowing the range of values ahead of time.

Comment: @haccks I meant to say that the necessary search will be O(n^2) so isn't linear.

Comment: @simonc; You know what mistake I did here? I thought searching array for a keyword. Editing my answer.

Comment: Why would you do a binary search?  Once the list is sorted, you only need to see if any two adjacent elements are equal.  And that can only be done linearly.

Comment: @DavidO; I was thinking about that and writing a code for that. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are with 1D array, you have to loop through each element, then check for each equal with an index bigger to prevent duplicating the result because `(arr[i]==arr[j] => arr[j]==arr[i])`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j, dup=0;
    int arr[10] = { 4, 7, 2, 4, 3, 1, 7, 9, 6, 5};
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        for(j = i + 1; j < 10; j++){
            if(arr[i] == arr[j]){
                printf("arr[%d] = %d = arr[%d] = %d\n", i, arr[i], j, arr[j]);
                dup++;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\nnumber of duplicates is %d\n", dup);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @haccks Sorry i wasn't not talkin about you. I said the chosen answer check it's revisions.

Comment: Don't worry about it :)