# Comparing if two arrays are equal

Tags: c

I want to compare if two arrays are equal. I know i have to loop through both arrays and see if they match. But how do i determine the longest array to use as an end to the loop.

EDIT

```
if (intToRoman(roman_integer, result))
{
    for(int i = 0; i < ???; i++ )
}
```

for example,

roman_integer[] = "MMM"
result[] = "MMMDCCLXXX"

Comment: If one array is the "longest", how can they be equal?

Comment: can you please add code which you have tried? and also elaborate your answer for better understanding.

Comment: `std::array` and `std::vector` both have equality operator defined. Save yourself the trouble and use those.

Comment: i don't know what to search. I know if one is longer then the other they are not equal. I need like an end to the loop. I'm basically comparing two strings

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14120346/c-fastest-method-to-check-if-all-array-elements-are-equal

Comment: @user3229707 `std::string` also has equality operator. If you mean a regular char array, well then tag your question with C. In C++ raw arrays are rarely every used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use strlen function to find the length of greatest string, like

```
int greatestlength=arrlength(a);
if(greatestlength<arrlength(b))
{
    greatestlength=arrlength(b);
}
```

use strlen inside of arrlength or directly or write your own code in arrlength whatever you want

Comment: you will easily find on google how to find a length of char array, that you have to code in arrlength, but if you want to learn programming do something by yourself....