# Check all values in an array

Tags: c++, c

I have an array:

```
int data[5] = {0,1,0,0,0};
```

I want to check if all elements of `data` are `1` or `0`. I tried it with `for loop` but didn't solve.

```
 int control = 0;
 for(a=0; a<5; a++){
    if(data[a] == 1) control = 1;          
 }
```

Is it possible? Thanks. (I'm very new to C)

Comment: [Google](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14120346/c-fastest-method-to-check-if-all-array-elements-are-equal).

Comment: If one element does not met the condition break the loop

Comment: @Lazy What do you want exactly to check: whether all elements are 1 or all elements are 0 or all elements either 1 or 0?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow `I want to check if all elements of data are 1 or 0.`

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`std::all_of`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/all_of/) and [`std::any_of`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/any_of/)

```
#include <algorithm>
int data[5] = {0,1,0,0,0};

if ( std::all_of(std::begin(data), std::end(data), [](int i){return i == 0;}) )
{
    std::cout << "All values are zero";
}

if ( std::all_of(std::begin(data), std::end(data), [](int i){return i == 1;}) )
{
    std::cout << "All values are one";
}
```

The nice thing is that these functions exhibit [short-circuiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) behavior, so they don't (necessarily) have to check every element.

Comment: std::begin(data) and std::end(data) - C++11

Comment: Am I missing something or aren't `begin` and `end` missing proper scope?

Comment: My mistake, [`begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [`end`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end) do indeed have the `std` prefix.

Comment: @Cyber You need std:: here, there is no argument dependent lookup

Answer (score 1):

And the C version: OP said *I want to check if all elements of data are 1 or 0.*

```
int data[5] = {0,1,0,0,0};
int a, zeros=0, ones=0;
for (a=0; a<5; a++) {
    if (data[a] == 0) zeros++;
    if (data[a] == 1) ones++;
}
if (zeros == 5)
    printf ("All elements are 0\n");
else if (ones == 5)
    printf ("All elements are 1\n");
else if (ones+zeros == 5)
    printf ("All elements are 1 or 0\n");
else
    printf ("Some elements are not 1 or 0\n");
```

Comment: What about 4 zeros and 1 one?

Comment: Thank you @Dieter Lücking I have improved the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
int control = 0;
for(a=0; a<5; a++)
 {
   if(data[a] == 1 || data[a]==0) 
     control++;
 }
if (control == 5)
 {
  cout<<"The array only contains 1 and 0";
 }
else
 {
  cout<<"The array contains elements other than 0's and 1's";
 }
```

Comment: You would probably want to add a condition before the output that checks if control is the same value as the length of the array. That way you could tell if it the array is all zeros or all ones. And from there you would need a mechanism to identify what control represents. Is it all zeros or all ones?

Comment: done,  i thought he would do it by himself. And the question is to find whether array contains any element other than 0 and 1 or not and i think i have done it right.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a for loop. You just need some way of keeping track of results. You can have two variables that represent true or false. If you start with an assumption that the array is either all zeros or all ones you can set the flags to true. Then in the for loop, if you ever find a contradiction, set the appropriate flag to false. In this case I'm just using int 0 for FALSE and int 1 for TRUE;

```
int data[5] = {0,0,0,0,0};
int all_zero = 1;
int all_ones = 1;

for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    if(data[i] == 1){
        all_zero = 0;
    }
    else{
        all_ones = 0;
```